# I'm a piece of cake. Anti-me can be fatal

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm a piece of cake.
>
> Anti-me can be fatal.

Hint:

> What's a prefix for "anti"?

---

*P.S. There are 10 answers here. I agree that there are 2 answers that really fits the riddle, but the rest are less fitting and some are stretches. Please reopen.*

Comment: rot13(Vfa'g "nagv" n cersvk nyernql?)

Comment: Anti-cake would be lethal to anyone in the same city so ...

Comment: -1 This puzzle had multiple solutions that all seem to match equally, the only thing differentiating the 'correct' solution from the other solutions is the hint which isn't a part of the riddle.

Comment: Actually, a piece of cake already fits this just fine. Anti-piece of cake is rather lethal.

Comment: @DavidMulder *This puzzle had multiple solutions that all seem to match equally* Please give an example. For reference, AC is not known to be fatal like a disease, if pound mean's a piece of cake, then so could chocolate,  icing and ice cannot be one word, random "simple" things cannot be foamed into a piece of cake, etc. etc.

Comment: @valsaysReinstateMonica Can you link me to a source please? Thanks!

Comment: @entioneveryone The riddle didn't say 'fatal like a disease', it only said 'fatal', and yes, for example 'AC can be fatal' totally works.

Comment: But nobody says that word is "piece of cake" - which is why the answer says the other word first

Comment: @MartinSmith [Alternative to piece of cake as epitome of ease](https://www.crosswordsolver.org/clues/a/alternative-to-piece-of-cake-as-epitome-of-ease.360060)

Comment: I've no idea what that site is and if the sentences there were even constructed by a human or a computer

Comment: @MartinSmith [The idiom "a piece of cake" emphasizes the ease of something.](https://study.com/academy/answer/what-does-the-idiom-a-piece-of-cake-mean.html)

Comment: Cake... or death?

Comment: @RewanDemontay *"Just because you see only two answers as fit does not mean everyone else does"* The same applies to the close voters. And invalidating the reason it was closed *is* a valid reason for reopening.

Comment: Why is this off-topic? I'm new to puzzling and this seems valid, at least to me.

Comment: @10Rep Gee, that's how I feel!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I may be off, but are you

> **ease**?

I'm a piece of cake.

> "easy"

Anti-me can be fatal.

> dying from "disease".

Answer (score 20):

You could be

> The letters CA

*I'm a piece of cake*

> This is a piece of the word "Cake"

*Anti-me can be fatal*

> Reversing CA gives AC. This [can give you a fatal electric shock](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/physics/p616/safety/more_current.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the correct answer, but I like the way you think!

Comment: I like this answer too, to be honest :)

Answer (score 9):

I think you are

> money

reason

> Several countries have [Pound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(currency)) as their currency. [Pound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_cake) is also a type of cake.
>
>  Exposure to [anti-money](https://rais.ornl.gov/tox/profiles/antimony.html) can be fatal.

Comment: But that would make "carrot", "chocolate", "yellow", "rainbow", "vanilla" all a *piece* of cake.

Comment: [anti-*****](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Rupoor) (spoiler)

Answer (score 6):

You are either:

> **Ice (-ing)**

Reason:

> 1) Icing is a common component *(piece)* of a well decorated cake.
>  2) *Anti-ice* or antifreeze can be fatal if you drink it.

Or alternatively this one is a bit more abstract and you are:

> **A lie**

... because:

> 1) [The cake is a *lie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_cake_is_a_lie)
>  2) The *truth* hurts.

You could even be *(and this one is a stretch)*:

> **Sugar**

... because:

> 1) Cakes have sugar as an ingredient
>  2) Insulin is kind of like *anti-sugar* as it reduces build up of blood sugar by moving it to the cells. Too much insulin is called [Hyperinsulinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinsulinism) and can cause type 2 diabetes which is fatal if untreated.

Comment: 1) rot13(vpr) and rot13(vprvat) cannot be one word. 2. If rot13(vafhyva) can be fatal by the phrase of "if too much", then you could say the same for pretty much every function of our body that helps us survive. Also, rot13(nagv-fhtne) is a thing; it's a movement to eat healthier.

Comment: The rot13(gehgu) is *not* fatal; it opens doors ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're

> Proton

Reasons:

> **I'm a piece of cake**  -> I hope this idiom should be taken literally. In the pudding or cake model of an atom, it was considered that the atom(cake) is positively charged with negative electrons embedded in it.
> Anti-me -> Antiprotons cause damage to DNA(fatal). Also the reaction(annihilation) of proton - antiproton releases enormous energy

Comment: I don't see how rot13(Nagvcebgbaf) are known to be fatal.

Comment: @entioneveryone: Scale up. An entire anti-cakeslice will be plenty.

Answer (score 4):

You could be

> MATTER

*I'm a piece of cake*

> Everything, including a piece of cake is made of matter.

*Anti-me can be fatal*

> Antimatter can damage cells (fatal)

Comment: I know "a piece of cake" = rot13(znggre), but I don't see how rot13(znggre) = "a piece of cake".

Comment: Maybe if you have a cold and pronounce it rot13(onggre) ;-)

Comment: @entioneveryone Maybe the answer is rot13(cvrpr bs pnxr)? Rot13(Naavuvyngvba bs n cvrpr bs pnxr znqr bs, fnl, 10 tenzf bs nagvznggre eryrnfrf raretl bs 430 xgba GAG. Gung zvtug or sngny.)

Answer (score 4):

Could you be

> Vaccination

*I'm a piece of cake*

> Getting a vaccination is very straightforward - it's a piece of cake

*Anti-me can be fatal*

> The anti-vaccination movement is causing vaccination rates for some diseases (e.g. measles) to drop to dangerously low levels (below the herd immunity threshold), which leads to outbreaks and deaths.

Comment: rot13(*"Trggvat n inppvangvba vf irel fgenvtugsbejneq - vg'f n cvrpr bs pnxr"*) uhh... no?

Comment: @entioneveryone I suppose that depends on where you are in the world, but for many people, it amounts to rot13(*ebyyvat hc lbhe fyrrir naq trggvat na vawrpgvba. V'z abg ersreevat gb gur qrirybczrag cebprff, whfg trggvat inppvangrq*)

Comment: In that case, I guess it would apply to a countless number of things, like eating, walking, talking, sleeping, etc.

Comment: @entioneveryone Sure. But "anti-walking", "anti-eating" etc aren't common terms, while rot13(*nagv-inppvangvba*) is

Comment: An argument that a word fits a line more simply because other words won't fit a different line doesn't work. The word must fit both lines well.

Comment: @entioneveryone  I'm not sure what you mean - that's not my argument at all. I was simply responding to your claim that anti-anything could also fit my argument, pointing out that those other examples aren't real terms, so wouldn't be reasonable answers. I wasn't referring to the first line of the riddle at all

Answer (score 2):

You are

> the letter C (upper- or lowercase)

Because

> Well, "c" is a piece (part) of "cake". Anti-C (and anti-c) antibodies can cause [hemolytic disease of the newborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolytic_disease_of_the_newborn), which can be fatal in severe cases.

Comment: [...found in approximately 80% of the United States population.](https://academic.oup.com/labmed/article/45/4/e142/2657931) Hmm... 80% of US...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is even close but
I think you are:

> depressants

Having depressants could be a piece of cake,

because

> all you need to do it consume it.

> Overdose of antidepressants is fatal.

Comment: Well in that case, rot13(nagvqrcerffnagf pna nyfb or pnyyrq n cvrpr bs pnxr, naq na bireqbfr bs qrcerffnagf pna nyfb or sngny).

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well, all you need is to consume rot13(nagvqrcerffnagf), and an overdose of rot13(qrcerffnagf) can also be fatal.

Answer (score -3):

You could be:

> Taking candy from a baby.

I'm a piece of cake:

> Nothing easier than that! Everybody knows.

Anti-me can be fatal:

> Candy are chocking hazard, giving one to a baby could be fatal.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is unfortunately an invalid answer; the [word] tag on the riddle means that the answer is a single word. Also, note that the intended answer (accepted, with a green checkmark) has already been found.